# How to change the default saving behaviour of Evince Document Viewer following highlight?

Tags: pdf, evince

If I highlight a sentence using Evince Document Viewer, it gets highlighted.

But after highlighting when I click `Ctrl` + `S` (that is save), it is giving pop up for saving each-time. Then eventually I will have to click replace each-time to save in the same PDF (screenshot below). This does not make a logic as we want the highlight to be saved in the same PDF without it asking each time.

[image]

How to just save without these kinds of prompts? I like Evince reader otherwise very much.